# How to load a Page with an intuitive swipe up transition?

Tags: dart, flutter

While Navigating from one screen to another, I want to achieve an animation like this, but I have no idea how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a somewhat similar design some time ago.
It was a lot of work involving `GestureDetector`s and animations.
You're welcome to check out [the source code on Github](https://github.com/marcelgarus/cards/blob/master/lib/cards_scaffold.dart).